# Horizontally centering text within TextView not working

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

This might sound very stupid but I am struggling with this so bear with me for a sec.

So I have this simple `TextView` that I want to have centered within the screen:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/helloTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:text="Hello!"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.464" />
```

I tried it with `wrap_content`and with `match_constraint` but I wasn't able to get it centered. When I do `wrap_content` the box is centered correctly but the text within is not as you can see here:

[image: 1st blueprint]

and when I do `match_constraint` it just centers it vertically but not horizontally:

[image: 2nd blueprint]

What am I missing out on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your TextView's xml as you posted it add:

```
android:textAlignment="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:textAlignment="center"
```

Comment: Can you provide a full example and brief explanation?